# What does the third equipment slot do?

Tags: kung-fu-strike

In Kung Fu Strike you are able to grant yourself various bonuses by equipping certain items. You have three customization slots and in the first two you can place pretty run of the mill items such as bracers, boots and so on.

The third slot, however, is not for items but for what would seem like a fighting style...
[image: Fighting style?]

However, I've tried out both "Lightning Fist" and "Lightning Kick" without noticing any difference while playing (I'll admit the game tends to get chaotic, but still). What does the equipped "Style" in this slot affect?